# Получение значения параметра из запроса (Requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каким образом можно получить значение параметра из запроса, если я перехожу по ссылке site.com/user/user.aspx, и добавляется параметр user site.com/user/user.aspx?user=12345678, необходимо получить значение из параметра user.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Добавляется? В смысле вы получаете перенаправление с первой ссылки на вторую?

Comment: Да, я получаю перенаправление.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
import requests

r = requests.get('http://site.com/user/user.aspx') 
user_id = parse_qs(urlparse(r.url).query).get('user')
```